# Interfacing Issue between PIC18F46K22 and I2C LCD with PCF8574AT module

Tags: microcontroller, pic, i2c, embedded, lcd

I'm facing a problem while interfacing a PIC18F46K22 microcontroller with an LCD screen using I2C communication. I have used a PCF8574AT I2C module and a 16x2 LCD screen. Everything works correctly in the Proteus simulator, but when I move to real-time usage, I fail to establish successful communication.

I have verified the connections between the PIC18F46K22, the PCF8574AT I2C module, and the LCD screen, and I'm confident that they are correct. I have also checked the I2C addresses used, and they appear to be correctly configured.

I am seeking assistance from the community to understand the reasons why real-time communication is not working. I have tried different coding approaches to interact with the I2C LCD, but so far, I haven't been successful.

If anyone has encountered this issue before or has experience in interfacing PIC microcontrollers with I2C LCD screens, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, advice, or potential solutions to resolve this problem.

I have included  my code for interacting with the I2C LCD below:
[enter link description here](https://files.fm/u/v5bjryh74)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sure the connections may be correct but we don't know how they should be to verify how they are. Also even if the connections are correct, how do you know the PIC is even running any code succesfully? Have you tried to blink a LED, at some defined rate like at 1Hz, and verified that the LED blinks and it blinks at correct rate?

Comment: Have you checked the "PCF8574AT I2C module" separately ?

Comment: Is the "PCF8574 I2C module" this one ? https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2016/05/12/serial-lcd-i2c-module-pcf8574/